# Initializing an object of a class inside another class using constructor with user input

Tags: c++

I want to create an object from a different class inside a class, but my constructor takes user input for initialization of the object.

This is my header file:

```
class assignment {
private:
    int assignment1;
    int assignment2;
    int assignment3;
public:
    assignment(int a1, int a2, int a3);
};

class marks {
private:
    assignment Assg;   //object in class
public:
    marks();
};
```

And my function definitions:

```
assignment::assignment(int a1, int a2, int a3) :assignment1(a1), assignment2(a2), assignment3(a3) {
    cout << "Initializer list Assignment constructor invoked" << endl;
}
```

I don't know how to create a constructor for `marks` so I can initialize the `assignment Assg`. Additionally, where do I take user input for the assignments 1, 2, and 3?

Comment: where to take user input -> depends on the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write an constructor for marks which takes three integer values and pass them to the assignment constructor.

```
marks::marks(int a1, int a2, int a3) : Assg(a1, a2, a3) {}
```

Or you could write setters to set the assignment values afterwards (but this would break the encapsulation)

```
class assignment {
private:
    int assignment1;
    int assignment2;
    int assignment3;
public:
    assignment(int a1, int a2, int a3);

    void setAssignments(int a1, int a2, int a3) { assignment1 = a1, ... } 
};
```

And also in marks

```
class marks {
private:
    assignment Assg;   //object in class
public:
    marks();
    void setAssignments(int a1, int a2, int a3) { Assg.setAssignments(a1, a2, a3); } 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use member initializer list to initialize `Assg`.

```
// mean that a1 = 1, a2 = 2, a3 = 3
marks::marks(): Assg(1, 2, 3) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are saying you want to take user input... This is the only way:

```
class marks {
private:
    assignment Assg;   //object in class
public:    
    marks(int a1, int a2, int a3) : Assg(a1, a2, a3)
    {

    }   
};
```

Or you can add a constructor that takes 0 parameters on your `assignment` class and add a func "create", or "initialize" so you can initialize the object later (otherwise you are forced to initialize it using the `member initializer list`)

Like

```
class assignment {
private:
    int assignment1;
    int assignment2;
    int assignment3;
public:
    assignment(int a1, int a2, int a3) : { Create(a1, a2, a3); }
    assignment() { assignment1 = assignment2 = assignment3 = 0; }
    void Create(int a1, int a2, int a3);
};

class marks {
private:
    assignment Assg;   //object in class
public:    
    marks() 
    {
       Assg.Create(1, 2, 3);
    }   
};
```